# How can I oblige a request by a moderator, who has deleted one of my answers and made a request at the same time

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4578440) has been unlocked today after remained locked for a week. A moderator (@robjohn) has deleted my answer (actually it was a too long comment) and at the same time asked me to let the mod know if the question is not undeleted when the question is unlocked. To send a comment to the mod, I need to undelete my answer. But that is not possible because it was deleted by a mod. I am not trying to get my answer undeleted. I only want to let the mod know that the question was not deleted when the question was unlocked. I am just trying to oblige a request. By the way, I have no idea why the mod wants to know that information. Here is my question. How can I address a comment to @robjohn?

EDIT

I know how deleting works and the criteria for deleting. I knew very well why my answer was deleted and I also accepted the reasons why it was deleted. The person (a moderator), who deleted my answer, requested some information. At that time, I did not know that it is possible to send the requested information by flagging the deleted question. That is why I posted this now-closed question. If anybody flagged my question because they think this a duplicate, they have not read my question. If this is indeed a duplicate, then why did the moderator @Tinkeringbell answered it instead of pointing out its redundancy?

Comment: Your answer there is not deleted, you posted it five minutes after posting here.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard No, you are wrong. I did not do that. You cannot see the deleted answer, because it is hidden. I posted it more than a week ago. Only I and, probably, the mod robjohn, who deleted it, can see it. This deleted answer was not an answer, It contains some hints only. It is true that the complete answer, which you are able to see,  was posted about 5 minutes after I posted my question here.

Comment: @Glorfindel No, I did not do that. This question has a long history. Since you are a moderator, you may be able to find out the whole story behind it. I kindly request you to read my comment I addressed to ShadowTheKidWizard.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Agree it's not duplicate, reopened. (The answers on the wrong dupe are not relevant at all for this question.)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Thank you very much.

Comment: @YNK off topic, but worth to mention since you are pretty active, your avatar is broken, can you please re-upload it? It's just showing broken image for everyone viewing your posts or profile.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Deleted posts can still be flagged. Use 'In need of moderator intervention' and type a custom comment, referring to the comments underneath your post and your actual request.

Moderators on the site will see such flags.

Comment: I flagged for moderator attention and got the problem resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

See: ["Is it our responsibility to police for competition/exam/etc questions?"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11191/510296) or ["Feature request for unlocking competition questions after a given time"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32458/510296):

**Banner comment**:

> "This question is locked in view of our policy about contest questions. Questions originating from active contests are locked for the duration of the contest, with answers hidden from view by soft-deletion. Please see the comments below for references to the originating contest.".

and the FAQ: ["Contest problem policy"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16775/510296):

> "**How we deal with on-going contest questions?**
>
> First, moderators will not actively patrol for contest questions.
>
> However, if the moderator team is made aware that a question posted to the Mathematics Stack Exchange is from an on-going contest:
>
> - We will **lock the question until after the end date of the contest**. Note that due to granularity in the locking system the expiration of the lock may not coincide exactly after the expiration of the contest; if you see a contest problem locked past the contest end date, feel free to **raise a flag and let the moderators know**.
> - We will **soft delete all answers** on the question; they will be restored after the contest finished. (Again, if you are a 10K user and see deleted answers to an expired contest problem, please raise a flag.)
> - We will, in the case not already present, provide links to the contest and its duration in the comments so the status of the contest can be easily verified.".

So you need to wait until the contest is over, then you can flag and request that your answer be undeleted.

Comment: The contest is over. That is why it is unlocked. I will try to flag the deleted answer for moderator attention.